# In an AMP page, how to prevent live blogs from polling when a user scrolls to the next/previous article in an infinite scroll?

Tags: amp-html

In my AMP page, I'm using the [amp-next-page](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-next-page/?format=websites) component to create an infinite scroll. Some articles in this infinite scroll are live blogs created using [amp-live-list](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-live-list/?format=websites). How do I prevent these live blogs from polling when a user scrolls to the previous/next article? (assuming they're active live blogs)